# lamp server check session

Tags: php, session

I have a LAMP server. I have started playing around with php cookies and sessions inside my scripts. Is there any way to check what or how many and what type of session I have active? I am able to check if cookies are being deleted from client side but sessions are server side with only a token in the client side.

Is there a command of some sort that would allow me to view active sessions (amount, time, session info) connected to my server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default PHP stores session on disk. Go do your sessions directory and check the active sessions there.

The file name of the session directory is the session token and the data stored in the file is the session data.

Comment: Can you tell me where the session directory is in?

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)

Comment: I looked inside /tmp but didn't find anything

Comment: Its not there. Make an empty page -> write <?php phpinfo(); ?> -> Execute this page and navigate to the module information of "session" -> find session.save_path . For me it was "/var/lib/php5"

Comment: In windows with WAMP server I found it under C:\wamp\tmp\ the files are sess_<session_id>

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Initially, I didn't find anything in that directory because I forgot to sudo. All the sessions appeared after that.

Comment: If you want to monitor it directly, a better way would be to install memcached, set php to store session information on memcached rather than storing on disk. Then use phpMemcachedAdmin to monitor sessions.